# How to execute a bash command with arguments from array elements?

Tags: bash

I am writing a simple bash script on Linux to ping some hosts, e.g.:

```
ping -c 1 google.com
ping -c 1 amazon.com
...
```

In my approach, I am loading the hosts from a separate file into an array and then loop over the  elements. The problem occurs when calling the ping command with elements from the array. Executing the following script gives me an error message.

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r hosts < hostnames.txt

for host in "${hosts[@]}"
do
    ping -c 1 ${host}
done
```

I guess there is something wrong with the syntax, but I couldn't figure it out yet.

Comment: You could also do this: `while read -r hosts; do ping -c "$host"; done < hostnames` provided the command in your while loop (ping in this example) does not consume/slurp stdin.

Comment: `IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r hosts < hostnames.txt`: Use `readarray`/`mapfile` instead. `mapfile -t hosts < hostnames.txt`. Read more at `help mapfile`

Comment: Thank you for your answer anishane. Reading the file content into an array works fine, also with the mapfile command or readarray. I tried your suggestion but it gives me the same error message: name or service not known.

Comment: The error occurs when the ping command is invoked

Comment: Simple debugging technique: `echo ${host}` before the ping ...

Comment: I also tried this to verify the array content. All names from the hostname.txt file are correctly displayed line by line.

Comment: The `read` command you have will *not* create an array, just a plain variable containing newline characters. Depending on how you check its contents, it's easy to be misled about what it contains. Use `declare -p hosts` to get a better idea what's actually being stored in the variable/array.

Comment: Run one ping command manually - `ping -c 1 google.com` Maybe there is some network issue - like DNS not responding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `hostnames.txt` was generated on a Windows machine?

Your hostnames have trailing `\r` characters, so the lookups fail.

Try this:

```
cp hostnames.txt hostnames.txt.bkp
dos2unix hostnames.txt.bkp hostnames.txt
```

And then run your script again.

If you don't have `dos2unix` installed and don't want to install it ... maybe you have `tr` already available. In that case this should do the trick, too:

```
tr -d '\r' < hostnames.txt.bkp > hostnames.txt
```

Comment: Whoa! Finally. Thank your for your help sir, that solved my problem. Btw. I created the hostname.txt file under linux with Xed editor but it seems like it appends an \r for each line.

Comment: Sweet .. pleased to hear that. And I never heard of `Xed`, seems like the wrong tool to use on Linux ;)

Comment: Out of curiosity: which method of conversion did you end up using? @Debo

Comment: dos2unix did the job :)

Comment: If the Xed editor doesn't have a config option to only use Linux line endings of `'\n'`, then time for a new editor. `vim` is available on most Linux systems and if you can remember "type `'i'`" for insert mode and "hit `[esc]`" to return to command mode -- you can use `vim`. (in command mode `:wq` writes (saves) and quits)

Comment: I need to correct myself. Well, I created the hostname.txt file under Linux but I copied the lines from a different file sent by a collegue. So the line endings of the copied lines were in a DOS format with \r (carriage return). Xed editor does not insert special characters by default. But it's still a good point to use an editor like vim to detect such differences quickly.